Point outside of projection domain (Error 2050)
I downloaded the World UTM grid from ESRI and placed it into a PostGIS database. I can see the CRS of the service is EPSG:4326 and that's also what I used for the PostGIS table.
I am getting input in EPSG:4326 (points), and need to find the correct UTM zone where the point is within.
SELECT * FROM public.utm_grid_simple WHERE ST_Within(
  ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(12.092128, 55.695088), 4326),
  public.utm_grid_simple.geom);

This works without any problem and the the UTM zone returned is 33N (EPSG:32633).
However, the next step is to extract cost lines within a buffer of 2 km around the input point, and it is here where I am getting the problem.
The coastlines are as well located in the PostGIS database and are in EPSG:4326. So to work with metres I use the just extracted information about the UTM zone.
SELECT * FROM public.coastline WHERE ST_DWithin(
  ST_Transform(coastline.geom, 32633), -- Transforms the polygon geometries from EPSG:4326 to EPSG:32632
  ST_Transform(ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(12.092128, 55.695088), 4326), 32633),
  2000 -- The distance in meters
);

Here I am getting error 2050 returned. --> Point outside of projection domain.
One question is on how I can overcome this problem.
The second question has something to do with the polygons for zones 31N - 37N.

The clear rectangular shape of all other UTM zones are not available. If I check the projected bounds for the UTM zones in question at epsg.io then there is also no indication for this alternating shape. Can somebody explain the irregular shape, and if WGS 84 /UTM zone 3*N might actually not the right CRS?

it would be simpler to work with geography objects that will handle metres for you

I need to have accurate length and area calculations, and the distance to look for coast lines in the vicinity will always be in meters, though it won’t be a static value. Is that possible when working with geography?

Yes, it will be more accurate than trying to pick a UTM zone

the issue here is that you are projecting the entire coastline dataset to a single UTM zone, which is expected to fail. And if you really want to work in UTM, you can always find the closest line using geography, then transform it to UTM (assuming it is not too long and spanning multiple zones..)

@JGH that's a good point and in hinside it's most likely better to only transform the objects that fall within the radius. Interestingly though, neither QGIS, ArcGIS or FME have a problem to reproject the entire dataset. Not so sure if it is expected that the transformation fails.
The other thing is of course calculating area and/or length leaves you with a distance specified in degrees (WGS84), which cannot be directly converted to metres. All you are left with is a rough estimate when trying to convert. So, I ended up by reprojecting the results to the appropriate UTM zone anyway. Works now
